# Mozilla: Selected option is not overwriting with previous selected one using jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-select, dropdown

I have dropdown with multiple options. have selected 1st option as selected later as per condition making another one as selected, its happening in HTML code but on browser showing first one is selected. case working fine with chrome but in mozilla not working. find below code.

```
var selectOption = "<option value='1' >1st option</option>";    
var selectOption = "<option value='-1' selected>--Select vehicle--</option>";
$('select[id$=ddlServiceVehicle]').prepend(selectOption);
```

*now using jquery as per condition want to make selected 1st option.*

```
    if(//condition)
     {
       $('select[id$=ddlServiceVehicle] option[value=1]').attr("selected","selected");
     }
```

but on UI its showing selected **--Select vehicle--** option. happening with mozilla only.

when i inspect element found

```
<option value='-1'>--Select vehicle--</option>
<option value='1' selected="selected">1st option</option>
```

still on UI 
[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution but still expecting more answer and clarification no my answer

i found solution that instate **.attr** used **.prop**

```
$('select[id$=ddlServiceVehicle] option[value=1]').attr("selected","selected");

$('select[id$=ddlServiceVehicle] option[value=1]').prop("selected","selected");
```

its working for me. but i would appreciate if any once can provide different answer.